# Struts2 validations not working properly

Tags: java, xml, jsp, validation, struts2

I'm new to struts2. I'm doing form validation using xml. But few of my feilds are getting invalidated everytime.

The filds which are getting invalidated are: 
police station, father's name, phone number and id number.

My validation for phone number is showing two error messages. One that i have provided in my xml and other is `Invalid field value for field "phone".`

Further, for client side validation, if i add `validate=true"` to my `<s:form>` tag, following error appears just after my form in jsp

```
FreeMarker template error!


Method public java.util.List org.apache.struts2.components.Form.getValidators(java.lang.String) threw an exception when invoked on org.apache.struts2.components.Form@17bb1c6
The problematic instruction:
----------
==> list tag.getValidators("${tagName}") as aValidator [on line 66, column 9 in template/~~~xhtml/form-close-validate.ftl]
 in include "/${parameters.templateDir}/${parameters.expandTheme}/form-close-validate.ftl" [on line 25, column 1 in template/xhtml/form-close.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: Method public java.util.List org.apache.struts2.components.Form.getValidators(java.lang.String) threw an exception when invoked on org.apache.struts2.components.Form@17bb1c6
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:130)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:428)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1508)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:593)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:547)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_002dcomplaint_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(register_002dcomplaint_jsp.java:368)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_002dcomplaint_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fdiv_005f0(register_002dcomplaint_jsp.java:233)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_002dcomplaint_jsp._jspService(register_002dcomplaint_jsp.java:166)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorKey(AnnotationActionValidatorMana
```

and following error appears on my console

```
SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-129] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/FIR_System] threw exception [Method public java.util.List org.apache.struts2.components.Form.getValidators(java.lang.String) threw an exception when invoked on org.apache.struts2.components.Form@17bb1c6 - Class: freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel
File: SimpleMethodModel.java
Method: exec
Line: 130 - freemarker/ext/beans/SimpleMethodModel.java:130:-1] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorKey(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:237)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:90)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.Form.getValidators(Form.java:280)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor321.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapper.invokeMethod(BeansWrapper.java:866)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:106)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:428)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.ConditionalBlock.accept(ConditionalBlock.java:79)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1508)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:221)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:199)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:259)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:593)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:547)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_002dcomplaint_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(register_002dcomplaint_jsp.java:368)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_002dcomplaint_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fdiv_005f0(register_002dcomplaint_jsp.java:233)
    at org.apache.jsp.register_002dcomplaint_jsp._jspService(register_002dcomplaint_jsp.java:166)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Please help me resolving these problems. I'm using **Struts 2.3.16** libraries.

**Update** Validations are **NOT** working when i leave some feilds blank. Exception part is still unresolved when `validate="true"` is ON in the struts form tag. Here's the updated code.

** Updated jsp form**

```
<s:form name="register-complaint" action="registerComplaint validate=""true" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="policeStation" label="Nearest Police Station"/>
    <s:select name="district" label="District" 
        list="{'Central Delhi','East Delhi','New Delhi','North Delhi','North-East Delhi','North-West Delhi', 'South Delhi','Soth West Delhi', 'West Delhi'}" />
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Your name"/>
    <s:textfield name="fathersName" label="Father's Name"/>
    <s:textarea name="address" label="Your Address"/>
    <s:textfield name="phone" label="Phone Number"/>
    <s:textfield name="email" label="Email address"/>
    <s:select name="idProof" label="ID Proof"
        list="{'Aadhar Card', 'Driving License','PAN Card', 'Passport', 'Electoral Card'}"/>
    <s:textfield name="idNumber" label="ID Number"/>
    <s:textfield name="distance" label="Distance from nearest police station"/>
    <s:select name="direction" label="Direction from nearest Police Station"
        list="{'East', 'North', 'North-East', 'North-west', 'South', 'South-east', 'South-west', 'West' }"/>
    <sj:datepicker name="dateAndTimeOfOccurance" label="Date and Time of Offence" timepicker="true" timepickerAaPm="true" timepickerGridHour="1" timepickerGridMinute="5" timepickerStepMinute="5"/>
    <s:textfield name="offence" label="Offence"/>
    <s:textfield name="section" label="section"/>
    <s:textarea name="particulars" label="Particulars of the offence"/>
    <s:textarea name="descriptionOfAccused" label="Description of accused"/>
    <s:textarea name="witness" label="Witnesses (with address)" />
    <s:textarea name="compaint" label="Detailed complaint" />
    <s:submit name="submit" label="Submit" align="center" />
</s:form>
```

** Updated Validation file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
         "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
           "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="policeStation">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Police Station Required.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="name">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Your name is required.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="fathersName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Father's name required.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="address">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Your address required.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="phone">
        <field-validator type="requiredInt">
            <message>
                Valid Phone number required.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="email">
        <field-validator type="email">
            <message>
                Enter a valid email id.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="idNumber">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Your ID proof number is required.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="distance">
        <field-validator type="double">
            <message>
                Please enter the distance from police station.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="dateAndTimeOfOccurance">
        <field-validator type="date">
            <message>
                Please enter the date and time of incident.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="offence">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Enter the offence.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="particulars">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Provide the details lost/damaged life/property.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>

    <field name="complaint">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>
                Describe your complaint in detail.
            </message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

**Action class**

```
public class RegisterComplaintAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ServletContextAware {

    private int id;
    private int userId;
    private String policeStation;
    private String district;
    private String name;
    private String fathersName;
    private String address;
    private int phone;
    private String email;
    private String idProof;
    private String idNumber;
    private float distance;
    private String directionFromPoliceStation;
    private Date dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
    private String offence;
    private String section;
    private String particulars;
    private String descriptionOfAccused;
    private String witness;
    private String complaints;

    private Map session;
    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext sc) {
        this.context = sc;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(getDateAndTimeOfOccurance());
            Class.forName(context.getInitParameter("db-driver-class"));
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(context.getInitParameter("db-url"), context.getInitParameter("db-user"), context.getInitParameter("db-password"));
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO FIR.COMPLAINTS (USERNAME, POLICE_STATION, DISTRICT, NAME, FATHER_NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, EMAIL, ID_PROOF, ID_NUMBER, DISTANCE_FROM_POLICE_STATION, DIRECTION_FROM_POLICE_STATION, DATE_AND_TIME_OF_OCCURANCE, OFFENCE, SEC, PARTICULARS, DESCRIPTION_OF_ACCUSED, WITNESS, COMPLAINTS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, (String) session.get("username"));
            ps.setString(2, getPoliceStation());
            ps.setString(3, getDistrict());
            ps.setString(4, getName());
            ps.setString(5, getFathersName());
            ps.setString(6, getAddress());
            ps.setInt(7, getPhone());
            ps.setString(8, getEmail());
            ps.setString(9, getIdProof());
            ps.setString(10, getIdNumber());
            ps.setFloat(11, getDistance());
            ps.setString(12, getDirectionFromPoliceStation());
            ps.setTimestamp(13, new java.sql.Timestamp(getDateAndTimeOfOccurance().getTime()));
            ps.setString(14, getOffence());
            ps.setString(15, getSection());
            ps.setString(16, getParticulars());
            ps.setString(17, getDescriptionOfAccused());
            ps.setString(18, getWitness());
            ps.setString(19, getComplaints());
            if (ps.executeUpdate() != 0) {
                session.put("successMessage", "Your Complaint has been successfully registered");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.put("errorMessage", "Unable to register your complaint " + e + getDateAndTimeOfOccurance());
            return ERROR;
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPoliceStation() {
        return policeStation;
    }

    public void setPoliceStation(String policeStation) {
        this.policeStation = policeStation;
    }

    public String getDistrict() {
        return district;
    }

    public void setDistrict(String district) {
        this.district = district;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getFathersName() {
        return fathersName;
    }

    public void setFathersName(String fathersName) {
        this.fathersName = fathersName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(int phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getIdProof() {
        return idProof;
    }

    public void setIdProof(String idProof) {
        this.idProof = idProof;
    }

    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    public float getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(float distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getDirectionFromPoliceStation() {
        return directionFromPoliceStation;
    }

    public void setDirectionFromPoliceStation(String directionFromPoliceStation) {
        this.directionFromPoliceStation = directionFromPoliceStation;
    }

    public Date getDateAndTimeOfOccurance() {
        return dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
    }

    public void setDateAndTimeOfOccurance(Date dateAndTimeOfOccurance) {
        System.out.println(dateAndTimeOfOccurance);
        this.dateAndTimeOfOccurance = dateAndTimeOfOccurance;
    }

    public String getOffence() {
        return offence;
    }

    public void setOffence(String offence) {
        this.offence = offence;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getParticulars() {
        return particulars;
    }

    public void setParticulars(String particulars) {
        this.particulars = particulars;
    }

    public String getDescriptionOfAccused() {
        return descriptionOfAccused;
    }

    public void setDescriptionOfAccused(String descriptionOfAccused) {
        this.descriptionOfAccused = descriptionOfAccused;
    }

    public String getWitness() {
        return witness;
    }

    public void setWitness(String witness) {
        this.witness = witness;
    }

    public String getComplaints() {
        return complaints;
    }

    public void setComplaints(String complaints) {
        this.complaints = complaints;
    }

}
```

PS: I waas forced to remove previous code from this post because of maximum character limit :(

Comment: Please show your Action

Comment: Don't mess up the client side and server side validations.

Comment: Looks like a type conversion error as Pravin says, although without further info, it's impossible to know. But phone numbers aren't really numbers.

Comment: @RomanC i read somewhere that `validate="true"` enables client side validation by auto-generating javascript files. So whats the harm?

@AndreaLigios and @daveNewTon i'll put updated code asap. And thanks for your responses guys

Comment: @maxx777 I think the problem is in your code. You'd better use available persistence framework for your DMLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

phone number is showing two error messages because you might have taken phone number as a `int` or `long` in your action.

If we don't provide anything(not even 0) in a text field whose data type is `int` or `long` in your action, then from JSP form it by default pass an empty string to your action.

So simply inside your action `setPhone()` method could not set a string(i.e empty string) to the `int` or `long` field & it show action

```
error i.e Invalid field value for field "phone".
```

If you have taken phone as `int` or `long` you should use `intRangeValidator` or `long validator` instead of `required` validator.

`freemarker.template.TemplateModelException` - This exception usually comes when you are trying to display a values from a list but that list you are not passing from action class or if you do not have `getters` & `setters` for given list.

Hope this will help you.

Please show you action class for further help.

Comment: thanks for your response. I  have corrected a few errors and i'll be puting the updated code soon. 
freemarker.template.TemplateModelException- it is appearing only when i have `valdiate="true"` in my form tag

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue in my project, then I got one solution on this Link https://coderanch.com/t/555477/framework/FreeMarker-template-error

Just change your action in the jsp page like

```
s:form action="loginprocess.action" validate="true"
```

I hope this will help you.